# Google cloud sql special characters

Tags: mysql, google-cloud-platform

In my google cloud mysql,  i insert this varchar data ','Out–of-Scope'

In the front end it appears as 'Out���of-Scope'

How do we handle special characters like this?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe a [Escape Sequence](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-literals.html) could help, like ',\'Out–of-Scope'

(I discard a charset problem as Google Cloud MySQL setup UTF-8 by default)